# VisualVM 1.32 doesn't connect to WAS (Websphere Application Server) 7.0.0.15

Tags: websphere

I'd be very pleased getting help from yours so many thanks in advance.
Can't manage to connect to a WAS server using VisualVM.

WAS properties setup:

> Servers->Server types->WebSphere application servers->server1->Process
>   definition->Java Virtual Machine -> Properties JVM
>
> -Djavax.management.builder.initial=
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999

WAS console output:

> INFO [com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl]:
>   connect(service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:9999/jmxrmi)
>   java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
>                   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:333)
>                   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:798)
>   Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed
>   connection during handshake
>                   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:817)
>                   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
>                   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:632)
>                   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
>                   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
>                   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
>                   at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:106)
>                   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:211)
>   Caused: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection
>   establishment; nested exception is: 
>                   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
>                   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:286)
>                   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
>                   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
>                   at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
>                   at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:97)
>   Caused: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is
>   java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection
>   establishment; nested exception is: 
>                   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake]
>                   at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:101)
>                   at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:185)
>                   at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
>                   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1886)
>                   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1856)
>                   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:257)
>   Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub
>                   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:338)
>                   at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl$ProxyClient.tryConnect(JmxModelImpl.java:496)
>                   at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl$ProxyClient.connect(JmxModelImpl.java:440)
>                   at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl.connect(JmxModelImpl.java:220)
>                   at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl.(JmxModelImpl.java:209)
>                   at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelProvider.createModelFor(JmxModelProvider.java:61)
>                   at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelProvider.createModelFor(JmxModelProvider.java:42)
>                   at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.model.ModelFactory.getModel(ModelFactory.java:111)
>                   at com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools.jmx.JmxModelFactory.getJmxModelFor(JmxModelFactory.java:69)
>                   at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxApplicationProvider.addJmxApplication(JmxApplicationProvider.java:267)
>                   at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxApplicationProvider.createJmxApplication(JmxApplicationProvider.java:185)
>                   at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.JmxApplicationsSupport.createJmxApplicationImpl(JmxApplicationsSupport.java:286)
>                   at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.JmxApplicationsSupport.createJmxApplicationInteractive(JmxApplicationsSupport.java:263)
>   [catch] at
>   com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.AddJMXConnectionAction$1.run(AddJMXConnectionAction.java:80)
>                   at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
>                   at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1957)

Thank you a lot again.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

Well,we've discovered the solution,kinda easy indeed.

The propertie -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=hostname was pointing to localhost instead of ip.

I Hope this info be usefull to someone more.

Thank you very much.

Regards.